# Sonar - quality profile - Technical importer for the MSBuild SonarQube ScannerChoose File

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, profile

Here is the documentation for quality profile in sonar: 
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles

But i don't find any doc for this option:

[image]

What's the meaning of this ?